# Override compareTo and sort using two strings

Tags: java

Lets say i've a Album class. How do i code the compareTo method so that when i've a ArrayList of Album object and i call

*Collections.sort()*

it will sort them in by title follow by singer in ascending order.

```
Public class Album implements Comparable{

private String title;
private String singer;
private double price;

.....

public int compareTo(){

// How to

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Album implements Comparable<Album> {
   ...
   public int compareTo(Album other) {
     int cmp = title.compareTo(other.title);
     if (cmp == 0) {
       cmp = singer.compareTo(other.singer);
     } 
     return cmp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would write it like

```
public int compareTo(Album other) {
    int primary = title.compareTo(other.title);
    return primary != 0 ? primary
                        : singer.compareTo(other.singer);
}
```

Personally however, I'd say it's arguable whether or not albums have a "natural ordering". Consider for instance if you, in the future, want to sort the albums on rating, or year.

If I were you I would probably create a `Comparator` for this purpose:

```
class TitleSingerComparator implements Comparator<Album> {
    public int compare(Album a, Album b) {
        int primary = a.title.compareTo(b.title);
        return primary != 0 ? primary
                            : a.singer.compareTo(b.singer);
    }
}
```

and sort the collection using

```
Collections.sort(albums, new TitleSingerComparator());
```

Comment: Your arguement seems reasonable. However for the sake of this question Louis's answer is what i'm actuall looking for. Up vote for you.!

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like

```
public class Album implements Comparable<Album>{   
  ...   
  public int compareTo(Album alb){
  int out  = this.singer.compareTo(alb.singer);     
  return out;
  }
}
```

variable "**out**" will store either positive value( any number greater than 0) or negative value( any number less than 0) or 0 in case when Strings are equal(i.e this.singer == alb.singer).